# Ansible inventory file in google cloud won't parse with any playbooks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, yaml

My inventory file won't work for any of my playbooks I've tested it on multiple playbooks including ones that have worked for me in the past. I can't seem to figure out what's misconfigured or where the issue might be. The inventory file is fairly simple, and I have all of the requisites for getting ansible to run, ansible is up to date, and I'm positive the credentials file is fine since it's been working on my terraform configuration. Any input is appreciated!

Inventory file:

```yaml
plugin: gcp_compute
projects:
  - projectName
auth_kind: serviceaccount
service_account_file: /home/.../.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json
keyed_groups:
  - prefix: gcp
    key: labels
  - prefix: tags
    key: tags
```

Error that comes up when I try to use inventory:

```
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/home/.../.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/.../.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/.../.local/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] (/usr/bin/python3)
  jinja version = 3.0.3
  libyaml = True
No config file found; using defaults
host_list declined parsing /home/.../inventory.gcp.yaml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
redirecting (type: inventory) ansible.builtin.gcp_compute to google.cloud.gcp_compute
Using inventory plugin 'ansible_collections.google.cloud.plugins.inventory.gcp_compute' to process inventory source '/home/.../inventory.gcp.yaml'
toml declined parsing /home/.../inventory.gcp.yaml as it did not pass its verify_file() method
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/.../inventory.gcp.yaml with script plugin: problem running
/home/.../inventory.gcp.yaml --list ([Errno 8] Exec format error:
'/home/.../inventory.gcp.yaml')
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 293, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
 ...
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/yaml.py", line 114, in parse
    raise AnsibleParserError('Plugin configuration YAML file, not YAML inventory')
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/.../inventory.gcp.yaml with ini plugin: Invalid host pattern
'plugin:' supplied, ending in ':' is not allowed, this character is reserved to provide a port.
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/inventory/manager.py", line 293, in parse_source
    plugin.parse(self._inventory, self._loader, source, cache=cache)
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/ini.py", line 137, in parse
    raise AnsibleParserError(e)
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/.../inventory.gcp.yaml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit
```

Comment: What is your Ansible version? Ansible introduced (no so recently anymore) something called _collection_, and you might have to fully qualify this inventory plugin name, adding its collection namespace: [`plugin: google.cloud.gcp_compute`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_inventory.html)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I'm sorry, I'm still new to using ansible. Where would I add in the collection namespace? Would that just be the first line of my inventory file?

Comment: Yes, swap `plugin: gcp_compute` for `plugin: google.cloud.gcp_compute`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I appreciate the feedback, after changing it I got a different error saying to switch it back to just "gcp_compute". I'm thinking there's something else going on.

Comment: Well, that does not look like an inventory file at all.  No hosts, no vars, no groups, nothing at all that looks like an inventory.

Comment: @Jack this is a dynamic inventory plugged on Google Cloud: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_inventory.html

Comment: Have you tried `plugin: google.cloud.gcp_compute`, per that link?